# Django: 'LeagueAdmin.inlines' must be a list or tuple

Tags: django, django-admin

Here is my code:

```
from League.models import Leagues
from League.models import Team
from django.contrib import admin

class TeamsInLeague(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Team
    extra = 1

class LeagueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['LeagueName']
    inlines = TeamsInLeague

admin.site.register(Leagues,LeagueAdmin)
```

it gives me the error:

```
'LeagueAdmin.inlines' must be a list or tuple.
```

It works fine when I remove `inlines = TeamsInLeague`

I am following the tutorial, not to the word, but trying to solve my own problem.

Comment: Do you know how Python represents lists or tuples?  Hint: It requires some punctuation.

Comment: i am a noob, and i am trying to solve two problems at one. learn python and learn django :D

Comment: here's a hint.  Don't do that.  Learn Python first.  Do the entire tutorial.  It will save you a lot of time in the future.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error is pretty clear -- `inlines` should be a list or tuple, not a class. Use

```
inlines = [TeamsInLeague]
```

or

```
inlines = (TeamsInLeague,)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Django admin reference page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin) has an example of a model with one inline item: even in that case, you need to make `inlines` a list.

So instead of what you have currently, use `inlines = [TeamsInLeague]`.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error as yours.
What I did implement is inserting a comma at the end of the closing tags but still inside the brackets

This is what I mean:

```
 filter_horizontal =('tags',)
```

In addition to this you can check the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin) on the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_display =  ('LeagueName',)
```